# using Doctrine in localhost works well but after uploading to C-panel, below error accrued

Tags: caching, doctrine

Uncaught Error: Class "Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\ArrayAdapter" not found,
but Symphony cache and Doctrine cache has been installed,
my composer.json:

```
 "doctrine/orm": "^2.11.0",
"doctrine/dbal": "^3.2",
"doctrine/annotations": "1.13.2",
"symfony/yaml": "^5.4",
"symfony/cache": "^5.4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because of version differences between your local and hosted environments, e.g. you might be running PHP 7.x locally and PHP 8.x on your hosted environment. This can be a bit of a struggle. The key things you need to know are:

- `composer.json` keeps a list of packages that you have said that your project needs. This is usually listed as point revisions, e.g. 1.x, 2.x, 3.x
- `composer.lock` lists the EXACT versions of the package that was installed when the `composer install` (or `composer upgrade`) command was used, e.g. 1.2.3
- `vendor/` is the resulting folder that was installed as the result of running `composer install`

When there is no `composer.lock` file, or `composer upgrade` is run, then composer will fetch the latest version of the available libraries based on the **current environment**, e.g. your local machine. If you then pick up the `vendor/` folder and upload it to your hosted environment, it may contain code that isn't compatible with the environment there.

I see people recommending to delete the `composer.lock` and `vendor` folder on the production machine, and then run `composer install` again. This is likely to resolve the issue, but it glosses over the fact that the code you're running in production is then different to what you were developing locally. On shared hosting it may not be immediately obvious how to run `composer install` as you may need access to a shell (e.g. SSH connection)

There are two ways forward - either:

- use your control panel to change the PHP version for your site to a version that you are running locally
- change your local dev environment to run the same version of PHP that your hosting environment is running

Be sure to always run the same version of PHP on dev and production to avoid these kinds of problems, and take the time to understand the purpose of `composer.lock` and how it is used to populate the `vendor/` folder with the exact code based on your current PHP version.

Comment: Funnily enough the reason I came across your post is because I just did this exact same thing to myself lol

Comment: finally clean uploading of Doctorine  directories was the solution